# Application Configuration

Tags: visual-studio, app-config, projects-and-solutions

Hi guys could someone please help me...my app.config file is not showing in my solution explorer but if i navidate to the directory where my project is saved the app.config file is there..any ideas where it has gone to?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the solution explorer, select your project, click show all files (second icon in the solution explorer's header). Your app.config will appear: right click it and choose "include in project".